# rails paperclip different file types problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip for uploading files, handling images is easy, but how can I handle images (png, jpg) and swf in the same upload, even pdf files, when I have to create different styles of the images but not the other formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the accepted answer is dead, it looks like the solution is:

```
  before_post_process :is_image?
  def is_image?
    !(asset_content_type =~ /^image/).nil?
  end
```

Assuming your attachment is named `asset`. Modify as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's apreciated

Comment: `before_post_process` is one of paperclip's supported events that you can hook into. If your handler returns false, it skips that event. In this case we're using is_image? which checks whether asset_content_type contains "image". That way paperclip will only attempt to process (resize) images. README talks about events: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,  a bit of ragged post but the idea is working quiet well http://www.mrkris.com/2009/09/15/paperclip-before_process-for-your-habitual-pornographic-needs/

Comment: This post is dead. Could you please paste the solution on here?

Answer (score 0):

Working code is

```
before_post_process :is_image?
def is_image?
  !(self.pc.content_type =~ /^image/).nil?
end
```

Where "pc" is your attachment name